# Mobile Menu Help, Add parent link to dropdown, disable parent link

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mobile, drop-down-menu

I've searched for a while for a way to do what I'm trying to accomplish but came up with nothing that could help me or explain it well enough for me to understand. I have this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3375c98s/1/) that I'm working on. I'm having some issues getting this to work the way I'm wanting it to. I would like to clone the parent link into the dropdown area and make sure the parent link is disabled (only on mobile) and only displays the dropdown when clicked. I know this can probably be accomplished by using JS since I **cannot** edit the HTML that is being outputted by the CMS I am working in. I'm sorry, I'm not very keen in JS, still learning. Please tell me if you need any more information. Thank you so much!

**HTML**

```
    <div class="main-nav">
    <ul id="megaMenu" class="menuContainer nav">
    <li class="menuItem"><a class="menuLink" href="resources"><span class="menuText">Resources</span></a>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="subnav" id="drop-resources">
                    <img alt="" src="http://s28.postimg.org/5riytyyvt/subnav_arrow.png">
                    <div class="left">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="/resources/resource-library">Resource Library</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="/resources/legal-resources">Legal Resources</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="/ask-the-experts/search-answers">Ask the Experts</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="/resources/community">Community</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="/resources/find-storage">Find Storage</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="right">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="/resources/industry-buyers-guide">Buyer's Guide</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="/resources/upcoming-auctions">Upcoming Auctions</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="/resources/tssa-forms-software">Forms Software</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="/resources/news/self-storage-news-magazine">Self Storage News Magazine</a>
                            </li>
                            <a href="/resources/community/open-for-business-blog">
                                <li>Blog</li>
                            </a>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="menuItem activeItem"><a class="menuLink" href="education"><span class="menuText">Education</span></a>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="subnav" id="drop-education">
                    <img alt="" src="http://s28.postimg.org/5riytyyvt/subnav_arrow.png">
                    <div class="left">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="/education/conference-trade-show/conference-and-trade-show-2015/general-info">Annual Conference</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="/education/executive-retreat-2015/home">Executive Retreat</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="/education/luncheon-calendar">Luncheons</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="right">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="/education/tssa-webinars">Webinars</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="/education/tssa-podcasts">Podcasts</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a target="_blank" href="/photos/txssa/sets/">Luncheon Photos</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="menuItem calendarnav"><a class="menuLink" href="calendar"><span class="menuText">Calendar</span></a>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="subnav" id="drop-calendar">
                    <img alt="" src="http://s28.postimg.org/5riytyyvt/subnav_arrow.png">
                    <div class="left">
                        <ul id="calendarOptions">
                            <li><a href="/calendar">All Calendar Items</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="66554bfc-9970-6e48-8fd4-ff0000ccdd76">Luncheon Calendar</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="9d574bfc-9970-6e48-8fd4-ff0000ccdd76">Deadline Calendar</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="71594bfc-9970-6e48-8fd4-ff0000ccdd76">Education Calendar</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="menuItem membership"><a class="menuLink" href="membership"><span class="menuText">Membership</span></a>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="subnav" id="drop-membership">
                    <img alt="" src="http://s28.postimg.org/5riytyyvt/subnav_arrow.png">
                    <div class="left">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="/membership/member-benefits" originalpath="/membership/member-benefits" originalattribute="href">Membership Benefits</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="/membership/join-tssa">Join REDACTED</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="/membership/pay-my-dues">Pay My Dues</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="menuItem aboutus"><a class="menuLink" href="about-us"><span class="menuText">About Us</span></a>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="subnav" id="drop-about">
                    <img alt="" src="http://s28.postimg.org/5riytyyvt/subnav_arrow.png">
                    <div class="left">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="/about-us/contact-us">Contact Us</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="/about-us/board">Board</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="/about-us/boardnominations">Board Nominations</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="/about-us/committees">Committees</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="/about-us/faqs">FAQs</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="/about-us/charitable-fundraising">Charitable Fundraising</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="menuItem membersonly"><a class="menuLink" href="members-only"><span class="menuText">Members Only</span></a>
            <div class="content">
                <div id="drop-members" class="subnav">
                    <img alt="" src="http://s28.postimg.org/5riytyyvt/subnav_arrow.png">
                    <div class="left">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="/members-only/my-account">My Account</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
    background:#112B50;
}

ul{
    list-style:none;
}

.main-nav {
  clear: both;
  margin-top: 20px;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

#megaMenu {
  float: right;
  padding-top: 15px;
  position:absolute;
}

.menuItem {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

.menuLink {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  background: url('http://s22.postimg.org/5ll1ux2r1/nav_arrow.png') no-repeat right 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-right: 15px;
  margin-right: 22px;
}


.calendarnav .menuLink {
  background: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.membersonly .menuLink {
  margin: 0;
  color: #FC0;
}

.menuItem .content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  left: 0;
  float: left;
  max-width: 344px;
  z-index: 10;
}

.membership .content, .aboutus .content, .membersonly .content {
  width: 200px;
}

.menuItem:nth-of-type(5) .content {
  left: -118px;
}

.menuItem:nth-of-type(6) .content {
  left: -82px;
}

.menuItem:hover .content, 
.menuItem:active .content,
.menuItem:focus .content {
  display: block;
}

.calendarnav:hover .content {
  display: none;
}

.subnav {
  border: 3px solid #476f93;
  background-color: #fff;
  float: left;
  width: 344px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px #333;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 8px #333;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px #333;
}

.membership .subnav, .aboutus .subnav, .membersonly .subnav {
  width: 200px;
}

.subnav img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 11px;
  left: 30px;
}

.menuItem:nth-child(5) .subnav img {
  left: 146px;
}

.menuItem:nth-child(6) .subnav img {
  left: 132px;
}

.membership .left, .aboutus .left, .membersonly .left {
  width: 180px;
}

/*******************************************
Media Queries
*******************************************/
@media(max-width:974px){
  .header-right {
    max-width: 100%;
    width:100%;
    padding: 15px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
}


@media(max-width:700px){
  .sf_cols.utilityLinks, .utilityLinks{
    text-align:center;
  }
}

@media(max-width:730px){
  .main-nav {
  margin-top: 0;
  }
  #megaMenu {
  float: right;
  padding-top: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .menuItem {
  float: none;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: transparent; /* changes the background-color of main nav */
  padding: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .menuLink {
  display: block;
  font-size: 15px;
  background: url('http://s22.postimg.org/5ll1ux2r1/nav_arrow.png') no-repeat right center;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-right: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  }
  .menuItem .content {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  padding-top: 20px;
  left: 0;
  float: none;
  max-width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  }
  .subnav {
  border: 0px;
  background-color: #fff;
  float: none;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px #333;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 8px #333;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px #333;
  }
  .content .left, .content .right {
  float: none;
  max-width: 100%;
  width:100%;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .calendarnav .menuLink {
  background: none;
  padding: 0;
  }
  .membership .subnav, .aboutus .subnav, .membersonly .subnav {
  max-width: 100%;
  width:100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .membership .content, .aboutus .content, .membersonly .content {
  width: 100%;
  }
  .menuItem:nth-of-type(5) .content {
  left: 0;
  }
  .menuItem:nth-of-type(6) .content {
  left: 0;
  }
  .membersonly .menuLink {
  margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .content li {
  border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
  }
  #header {
  max-height: 100%; /*300px*/
  margin-bottom: 45px;
  overflow: auto; /*hidden*/
  float: none;
  }
  .header-right, #content {
  float: left;
  max-width: 715px;
  width: 100%;
  }
  .menuItem:nth-child(5) .subnav img {
  left: 50%;
  }
  .menuItem:nth-child(6) .subnav img {
  left: 50%;
  }
  .subnav img {
  left: 50%;
  }

}



@media (max-width:600px){
  .canidates{
    width:100%;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
  }

  .sf_colsOut.sf_2cols_1_50,
  .sf_colsOut.sf_2cols_2_50{
    width:100%;
  }
  .sf_2cols_2_50 .sf_2cols_2in_50{
    margin-left:0 !important;
  }

}
```

**JS**

```
//This JS was on the page already, maybe you can utilize it in someway.
$(document).ready(function(){

  var allPanels = $('.sflistItemContent').hide();
  $('.sflistListItem:first > .sflistItemContent').show();

  $('.sflistItemTitle').click(function() {
    allPanels.slideUp();
    $('.expanded').removeClass('expanded');
    $(this).next().slideDown();
    $(this).addClass('expanded');
    return false;
  });

  $('.menuItem:nth-child(3n)').addClass('calendarnav');
  $('.menuItem:nth-child(4n)').addClass('membership');
  $('.menuItem:nth-child(5n)').addClass('aboutus');
  $('.menuItem:nth-child(6n)').removeClass('calendarnav').addClass('membersonly');


  // Form input hide/display default text on focus/blur
  $(".sfsearchTxt").focus(function() {
          if(this.value == this.defaultValue) {
                  this.value = "";
          }
  }).blur(function() {
          if(!this.value.length) {
                  this.value = this.defaultValue;
          }
  });     


});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I worked on this for about an hour and a half, and it was quite some work. Basically, what I did was copy the parent links and added it to their respective dropdown lists as the first item and gave them a class of "clone". That way, using css and media queries, those options only appear on a mobile layout and disappear when you resize the window back to full desktop view. And you said it yourself, yes it requires some javascript to create the click events that will make the dropdowns appear when their respective parent link is clicked. To do that I used "event.preventDefault();" which stops the link from going to the page where it's supposed to take you and then immediately use show() to make the dropdown appear (it will also put away the dropdown list if you click it again using hide(); ). Lastly, using your css, I deactivated the hover effects on the dropdown menus, but only on mobile layouts. The desktop layout has remained intact. Here's the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($(".menuItem").css("float") == "left") {
        $(".content").css("display", "");   
    }
    var showDropDown = function(id) {
        if ($(".menuItem").css("float") == "none") {
            event.preventDefault();
            var id = "#" + id;
            var dropdownSelector = $(id).parent().children(".content");
            if (dropdownSelector.css("display") == "none") {
                dropdownSelector.show();
            }
            else {
                dropdownSelector.hide();
                dropdownSelector.css("display", "");
            }
        }
    };
    
    $("#resources").click(function() {showDropDown($("#resources").attr("id"))});
    $("#education").click(function() {showDropDown($("#education").attr("id"))});
    $("#calendar").click(function() {showDropDown($("#calendar").attr("id"))});
    $("#membership").click(function() {showDropDown($("#membership").attr("id"))});
    $("#about-us").click(function() {showDropDown($("#about-us").attr("id"))});
    $("#members-only").click(function() {showDropDown($("#members-only").attr("id"))});
});
```

```css
body{
    background:#112B50;
}

ul{
    list-style:none;
}

.main-nav {
  clear: both;
  margin-top: 20px;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

#megaMenu {
  float: right;
  padding-top: 15px;
  position:absolute;
}

.menuItem {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

.menuLink {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  background: url('http://s22.postimg.org/5ll1ux2r1/nav_arrow.png') no-repeat right 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-right: 15px;
  margin-right: 22px;
}


.calendarnav .menuLink {
  background: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.membersonly .menuLink {
  margin: 0;
  color: #FC0;
}

.menuItem .content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  left: 0;
  float: left;
  max-width: 344px;
  z-index: 10;
}

.membership .content, .aboutus .content, .membersonly .content {
  width: 200px;
}

.menuItem:nth-of-type(5) .content {
  left: -118px;
}

.menuItem:nth-of-type(6) .content {
  left: -82px;
}

.menuItem:hover .content, 
.menuItem:active .content,
.menuItem:focus .content {
  display: block;
}

.calendarnav:hover .content {
  display: none;
}

.subnav {
  border: 3px solid #476f93;
  background-color: #fff;
  float: left;
  width: 344px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px #333;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 8px #333;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px #333;
}

.membership .subnav, .aboutus .subnav, .membersonly .subnav {
  width: 200px;
}

.subnav img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 11px;
  left: 30px;
}

.menuItem:nth-child(5) .subnav img {
  left: 146px;
}

.menuItem:nth-child(6) .subnav img {
  left: 132px;
}

.membership .left, .aboutus .left, .membersonly .left {
  width: 180px;
}

.clone {
    display:none;
}

/*******************************************
Media Queries
*******************************************/
@media(max-width:974px){
  .header-right {
    max-width: 100%;
    width:100%;
    padding: 15px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
}


@media(max-width:700px){
  .sf_cols.utilityLinks, .utilityLinks{
    text-align:center;
  }
}

@media(max-width:730px){
  .main-nav {
  margin-top: 0;
  }
  #megaMenu {
  float: right;
  padding-top: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .menuItem {
  float: none;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: transparent; /* changes the background-color of main nav */
  padding: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .menuLink {
  display: block;
  font-size: 15px;
  background: url('http://s22.postimg.org/5ll1ux2r1/nav_arrow.png') no-repeat right center;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-right: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  }
  .menuItem .content {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  padding-top: 20px;
  left: 0;
  float: none;
  max-width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  }
  .subnav {
  border: 0px;
  background-color: #fff;
  float: none;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px #333;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 8px #333;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px #333;
  }
  .content .left, .content .right {
  float: none;
  max-width: 100%;
  width:100%;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .calendarnav .menuLink {
  background: none;
  padding: 0;
  }
  .membership .subnav, .aboutus .subnav, .membersonly .subnav {
  max-width: 100%;
  width:100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .membership .content, .aboutus .content, .membersonly .content {
  width: 100%;
  }
  .menuItem:nth-of-type(5) .content {
  left: 0;
  }
  .menuItem:nth-of-type(6) .content {
  left: 0;
  }
  .membersonly .menuLink {
  margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .content li {
  border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
  }
  #header {
  max-height: 100%; /*300px*/
  margin-bottom: 45px;
  overflow: auto; /*hidden*/
  float: none;
  }
  .header-right, #content {
  float: left;
  max-width: 715px;
  width: 100%;
  }
  .menuItem:nth-child(5) .subnav img {
  left: 50%;
  }
  .menuItem:nth-child(6) .subnav img {
  left: 50%;
  }
  .subnav img {
  left: 50%;
  }
    .menuItem:hover .content  {
        display: none;
    }
    
    .calendarnav:hover .content {
        display: none;
    }
    
    .clone {
        display:block;
    }
}



@media (max-width:600px){
  .canidates{
    width:100%;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
  }

  .sf_colsOut.sf_2cols_1_50,
  .sf_colsOut.sf_2cols_2_50{
    width:100%;
  }
  .sf_2cols_2_50 .sf_2cols_2in_50{
    margin-left:0 !important;
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-nav">
    <ul id="megaMenu" class="menuContainer nav">
        <li class="menuItem"><a id="resources" class="menuLink" href="resources"><span class="menuText">Resources</span></a>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="subnav" id="drop-resources">
                    <img alt="" src="http://s28.postimg.org/5riytyyvt/subnav_arrow.png">
                    <div class="left">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="clone"><a href="resources">Resources</a>
                            <li><a href="/resources/resource-library">Resource Library</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="/resources/legal-resources">Legal Resources</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="/ask-the-experts/search-answers">Ask the Experts</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="/resources/community">Community</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="/resources/find-storage">Find Storage</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="right">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="/resources/industry-buyers-guide">Buyer's Guide</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="/resources/upcoming-auctions">Upcoming Auctions</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="/resources/tssa-forms-software">Forms Software</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="/resources/news/self-storage-news-magazine">Self Storage News Magazine</a>
                            </li>
                            <a href="/resources/community/open-for-business-blog">
                                <li>Blog</li>
                            </a>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="menuItem activeItem"><a id="education" class="menuLink" href="education"><span class="menuText">Education</span></a>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="subnav" id="drop-education">
                    <img alt="" src="http://s28.postimg.org/5riytyyvt/subnav_arrow.png">
                    <div class="left">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="clone"><a href="education">Education</a>
                            <li><a href="/education/conference-trade-show/conference-and-trade-show-2015/general-info">Annual Conference</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="/education/executive-retreat-2015/home">Executive Retreat</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="/education/luncheon-calendar">Luncheons</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="right">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="/education/tssa-webinars">Webinars</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="/education/tssa-podcasts">Podcasts</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a target="_blank" href="/photos/txssa/sets/">Luncheon Photos</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="menuItem"><a id="calendar" class="menuLink" href="calendar"><span class="menuText">Calendar</span></a>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="subnav" id="drop-calendar">
                    <img alt="" src="http://s28.postimg.org/5riytyyvt/subnav_arrow.png">
                    <div class="left">
                        <ul id="calendarOptions">
                            <li class="clone"><a href="calendar">Calendar</a>
                            <li><a href="/calendar">All Calendar Items</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="66554bfc-9970-6e48-8fd4-ff0000ccdd76">Luncheon Calendar</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="9d574bfc-9970-6e48-8fd4-ff0000ccdd76">Deadline Calendar</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="71594bfc-9970-6e48-8fd4-ff0000ccdd76">Education Calendar</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="menuItem membership"><a id="membership" class="menuLink" href="membership"><span class="menuText">Membership</span></a>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="subnav" id="drop-membership">
                    <img alt="" src="http://s28.postimg.org/5riytyyvt/subnav_arrow.png">
                    <div class="left">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="clone"><a href="membership">Membership</a>
                            <li><a href="/membership/member-benefits" originalpath="/membership/member-benefits" originalattribute="href">Membership Benefits</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="/membership/join-tssa">Join REDACTED</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="/membership/pay-my-dues">Pay My Dues</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="menuItem aboutus"><a id="about-us" class="menuLink" href="about-us"><span class="menuText">About Us</span></a>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="subnav" id="drop-about">
                    <img alt="" src="http://s28.postimg.org/5riytyyvt/subnav_arrow.png">
                    <div class="left">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="clone"><a href="about-us">About Us</a>
                            <li><a href="/about-us/contact-us">Contact Us</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="/about-us/board">Board</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="/about-us/boardnominations">Board Nominations</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="/about-us/committees">Committees</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="/about-us/faqs">FAQs</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="/about-us/charitable-fundraising">Charitable Fundraising</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="menuItem membersonly"><a id="members-only" class="menuLink" href="members-only"><span class="menuText">Members Only</span></a>
            <div class="content">
                <div id="drop-members" class="subnav">
                    <img alt="" src="http://s28.postimg.org/5riytyyvt/subnav_arrow.png">
                    <div class="left">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="clone"><a href="members-only">Members Only</a>
                            <li><a href="/members-only/my-account">My Account</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Also here's the jsfiddle where I did my work: http://jsfiddle.net/381nxmuo/

Comment: There's a lot of things that were added and modified, and the jQuery script probably makes it more confusing so if you're not sure what's what, let me know. It was such a pain the first time I tried building something like this.

Comment: You are a mad genius! I'll let you know if I need anything. Thank you so much for taking the time to figure it out!